# How to create map property with key=beanID of someBean ,value=someBean

Tags: java, spring

How to create map property with key=beanID of someBean ,value=someBean

For example:
I have in my spring file:

```
<bean id="Service" class="Service" 
<property name="tasks">
      <map> 
          ???
      </map>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="FirstTaskID" class="TaskType"/>
<bean id="SecondTaskID" class="TaskType"/>
/>
```

I want to create such Map tasks:
{("FirstTaskID", value-ref = "FirstTaskID"),("SecondTaskID", value-ref = "SecondTaskID")}

I use spring 2.0.2.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="tasks">
  <map>
      <entry key="FirstTaskID" value-ref="FirstTaskID"/>
      <entry key="SecondTaskID" value-ref="SecondTaskID"/>
  </map>
</property>
```

is what's documented for 3.0.x. For 2.0.x, [what's documented](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-collection-elements) is

```
<property name="someMap">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <value>FirstTaskID</value>
            </key>
            <ref bean="FirstTaskID" />
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <value>SecondTaskID</value>
            </key>
            <ref bean="SecondTaskID" />
        </entry>
    </map>
</property>
```